# How to Bind data to a Custom ListView with Xamarin Android with Reactive UI

Tags: c#, listview, data-binding, xamarin.android, reactiveui

I am using Xamarin Android with Reactive UI and Not using Xamarin Forms. I have a Custom ListView(I have defined it's layout as xaml). I have no idea how to bind this control into a observableCollection in ViewModel using ***OneWayBind*** method in the activity class.

I wrote it as,

```
this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, x => x.OutletListing, x => x.List).DisposeWith(SubscriptionDisposables);
```

But gives,

> System.ArgumentException: Can't convert
>   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection1 to
>   Android.Widget.ListView. To fix this, register a IBindingTypeConverter

I saw in tutorials **Xamarin** Forms has used ***ItemSource*** property for this.

Could anyone please give a solution for this .
thanks in advance.

**Update**
I have no idea how to go ahead with the given answer. I want to figure this out more.

here is my ViewModel class.

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using Android.App;
    using Android.Content;
    using Android.OS;
    using Android.Runtime;
    using Android.Views;
    using Android.Widget;
    using ReactiveUI;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Reactive.Linq;
    using Splat;
    using System.Reactive.Disposables;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.ViewModels
    {
        public class StockTakeVM : ReactiveObject
        {
            protected Lazy<CompositeDisposable> ViewModelBindings = new Lazy<CompositeDisposable>(() => new CompositeDisposable());
            public void RegisterObservables()
            {
                StockItemListing = new ReactiveList<StockItemListingResult>();

                this.LoadStockItems = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<FilterParams, List<StockItemListingResult>>(
                    async filter =>
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Load StockItemListing #1");
                        var r = await GetStockItemListing(filter);
                        return r;
                    },
                        Observable.Return(true))
                    .DisposeWith(ViewModelBindings.Value);

                this.LoadStockItems.ThrownExceptions
                    .Subscribe(ex =>
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Load StockItemListing Failed");
                    });

                this.LoadStockItems
                   .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                   .Subscribe(result =>
                   {

                       StockItemListing.Clear();
                       foreach (var item in result)
                           StockItemListing.Add(item);

                   });

            }

            async Task<List<StockItemListingResult>> GetStockItemListing(FilterParams filter)
            {
                List<StockItemListingResult> items = new List<StockItemListingResult>() {  

                new StockItemListingResult
                {
                    StockItemName = "PORK SAUSAGES (ECONOMY) 500G",
                    StockItemCode = "CODE: J3103386",
                    StockItemAmt = "150"
                },

                new StockItemListingResult
                {
                    StockItemName = "COLLAR BACON  500G",
                    StockItemCode = "CODE: J3155667",
                    StockItemAmt = "152"
                },

                new StockItemListingResult
                {
                    StockItemName = "COLLAR BACON 1KG",
                    StockItemCode = "CODE: J2344545",
                    StockItemAmt = "200"
                },

                new StockItemListingResult
                {
                    StockItemName = "PORK CHIPPOLATAS 1KG",
                    StockItemCode = "CODE: J31038779",
                    StockItemAmt = "378"
                },

                new StockItemListingResult
                {
                    StockItemName = "PORK SAUSAGES (ECONOMY) 500G",
                    StockItemCode = "CODE: J3103386",
                    StockItemAmt = "23"
                },
                new StockItemListingResult
                {
                    StockItemName = "PORK SAUSAGES (ECONOMY) 500G",
                    StockItemCode = "CODE: J3103386",
                    StockItemAmt = "454"
                },

                new StockItemListingResult
                {
                    StockItemName = "COLLAR BACON  500G",
                    StockItemCode = "CODE: J3155667",
                    StockItemAmt = "123"
                },

                new StockItemListingResult
                {
                    StockItemName = "COLLAR BACON 1KG",
                    StockItemCode = "CODE: J2344545",
                    StockItemAmt = "675"
                },

                new StockItemListingResult
                {
                    StockItemName = "PORK CHIPPOLATAS 1KG",
                    StockItemCode = "CODE: J31038779",
                    StockItemAmt = "11"
                },

                new StockItemListingResult
                {
                    StockItemName = "PORK SAUSAGES (ECONOMY) 500G",
                    StockItemCode = "CODE: J3103386",
                    StockItemAmt = "34"
                }


            };
                return items;
            }


            // Observable Properties
            ReactiveList<StockItemListingResult> _stockItemListing;
            public ReactiveList<StockItemListingResult> StockItemListing
            {
                get { return _stockItemListing; }
                private set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _stockItemListing, value); }
            }

            ReactiveCommand<FilterParams, List<StockItemListingResult>> _loadStockItems;
            public ReactiveCommand<FilterParams, List<StockItemListingResult>> LoadStockItems
            {
                get { return _loadStockItems; }
                private set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _loadStockItems, value); }
            }
            public StockTakeVM()
            {
                RegisterObservables();
            }

        }

        public class StockItemListingResult : ReactiveObject
        {
            Guid _stockItemId;
            public Guid Id
            {
                get { return _stockItemId; }
                set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _stockItemId, value); }
            }

            string _stockItemName;
            public string StockItemName
            {
                get { return _stockItemName; }
                set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _stockItemName, value); }
            }

            string _stockItemCode;
            public string StockItemCode
            {
                get { return _stockItemCode; }
                set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _stockItemCode, value); }
            }
            string _stockItemAmt;
            public string StockItemAmt
            {
                get { return _stockItemAmt; }
                set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _stockItemAmt, value); }
            }

        }


    }
```

And My Activity Class is as follows

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using ReactiveUI;
using Android.Support.V4.Widget;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.ViewModels;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.Util;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.Models;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Splat;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.Views.StockTake
{
    [Activity(Label = "StockTakeActivity", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/MainTheme")]
    public class StockTakeActivity : DistributrBaseActivity<StockTakeVM>
    {
        private Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView _searchView;
        public ListView List { get; private set; }
        ReactiveList<StockItemListingResult> StockListItems;
        StockTakeScreenAdapter osadapter;
        List<StockItemModel> items = new List<StockItemModel>();

        public StockTakeActivity()
        {
            this.ViewModel = new StockTakeVM();
            this.StockListItems = new ReactiveList<StockItemListingResult>();
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Activity_StockTake);


            this.Bind(ViewModel, x => x.StockItemListing, x => x.StockListItems);

            //checking whether change happens
            //        StockListItems.ItemChanged
            //        .Where(x => x.PropertyName == "StockItemAmt" && x.Sender.StockItemAmt)
            //        .Select(x => x.Sender)
            //        .Subscribe(x => {
            //            Console.WriteLine("Make sure to save {0}!", x.DocumentName);
            //});
            this.WhenAnyValue(view => view.ViewModel.StockItemListing)
            .Where(listing => listing != null)
            .Select(listing => new DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.Util.ReactiveListAdapter<StockTakeVM>(listing, Resource.Layout.Activity_StockTake))
            .BindTo(this, view => view.List.Adapter);

            this.ViewModel.LoadStockItems.Execute(new FilterParams
            {
                NameFilter = "",

                Status = "All"
            }).Subscribe();

            //List = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.List);

            SetupReactiveLists(this);
            var toolbarST = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbarST);
            toolbarST.InflateMenu(Resource.Menu.StockTakeSearch);
            toolbarST.Title = "Stock Take";




        }
        public void SetupReactiveLists(Activity context)
        {
            List = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.List);

            foreach (var item in StockListItems)
            {
                StockItemModel stockitem = new StockItemModel
                {
                    StockItemName = item.StockItemName,
                    StockItemCode = item.StockItemCode
                };

                items.Add(stockitem);
            }
            osadapter = new StockTakeScreenAdapter(this, items);
            List.Adapter = osadapter;

            List.ItemClick += OnListItemClick;

        }




}
```

here is my Listadapter class.

```
public class StockTakeScreenAdapter : BaseAdapter<StockItemModel>
    {
        List<StockItemModel> items;
        Activity context;
        public StockTakeScreenAdapter(Activity context, List<StockItemModel> items) : base()
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.items = items;
        }
        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
        public override StockItemModel this[int position]
        {
            get { return items[position]; }
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get { return items.Count; }
        }
        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var item = items[position];
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) 
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ViewCell_StockTake, null);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.stockitem_name).Text = item.StockItemName;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.stockitem_code).Text = item.StockItemCode;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.stockitem_amt).Text = item.StockItemAmt;
            return view;
```

}
    }

### Here are my questions

1. Should I want to create another reactive List in the Activity Class            in order to bind.
2. If I changed the value of a list item , does it update the list (I expect to update the value of a list item using another fragment class.)

I am new to android development with RX. Pardon me if I mess up the things. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You would use an adapter to accomplish this on Android, just like you would without Reactive Extensions.

In case you want to use a ListView with RxUI, you'd use a `ReactiveListAdapter`. Unfortunately this isn't really documented yet, so you might want to take a look at the source code: https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/develop/src/ReactiveUI/Platforms/android/ReactiveListAdapter.cs

The gist is you create an instance with the `ReactiveList` supplying the data. The adapter then watches for changes in this list to know when it needs to be updated.

Example:

```
this.WhenAnyValue (view => view.ViewModel.OutletListing)
    .Where (listing => listing != null)
    .Select (listing => new ReactiveListAdapter (listing, MyViewCreator))
    .BindTo (this, view => view.List.Adapter);
```

`MyViewCreator` is a delegate which accepts the initial ViewModel from your list and the parent ViewGroup so you can inflate the row with initial data and return the resulting View.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this in a bit and return

Comment: hi , hello I have no idea how to go with your answer. I have updated question. Canyou help me .Thanks

Comment: To answer your questions:
1. No, just create the correct list in your ViewModel, that's what it's for.
2. Only if you enable `ChangeTrackingEnabled` on the `ReactiveList`.

I'm not sure what your `DistributrIII.Mobile.Droid.Util.ReactiveListAdapter` contains.