# How to correctly implement ReactiveUI ReactiveList with Xamarin.Android ListView with Customized ListView Layout

Tags: listview, xamarin.android, reactiveui

I am using Xamarin.Android with ReactiveUI and I am trying to implement a **Custom ListView** with ReactiveUI.

Is there any way to data bind to the custom implemented controls such as EditTexts, TextViews in the **ListView** just like inflating via a ListView Adopter and by setting a onClickListner?

I have seen concepts with less examples and documentation like `ReactiveListAdopter` can this be used?

**Adopter**

```
public class OutletScreenAdopter : BaseAdapter<OutletModel>
        {
            List<OutletModel> items;
            Activity context;
            public OutletScreenAdopter(Activity context, List<OutletModel> items) : base()
            {
                this.context = context;
                this.items = items;
            }
            public override long GetItemId(int position)
            {
                return position;
            }
            public override OutletModel this[int position]
            {
                get { return items[position]; }
            }
            public override int Count
            {
                get { return items.Count; }
            }
            public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                var item = items[position];
                View view = convertView;
                if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
                    view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ViewCell_OutletBasic, null);
                view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ViewCellOutletTxtOutletTitle).Text = item.OutletName;
                view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.ViewCellOutletTxtOutletCode).Text = item.OutletCode;

                return view;
            }
        }
```

**Main Activity**

```
ReactiveList<OutletListResult> OutletListItems;
public ListView OutletListViewMain { get; private set; }
....

public void SetupReactiveLists(Activity context)
        {
            List<OutletModel> items = new List<OutletModel>();

            foreach (var item in OutletListItems)
            {
                OutletModel outlet = new OutletModel
                {
                    OutletName = item.OutletName,
                    OutletCode = item.OutletCode
                };

                items.Add(outlet);
            }

            OutletListViewMain.Adapter = new OutletScreenAdopter(context, items);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shared an example here today: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47527601/2782141

You can use the `ReactiveListAdapter` and supply your items and a View-creating delegate in the constructor. That's all there is to it.

But as Julien Mialon is saying, performance, and usability-wise it's better to switch to a RecyclerView.

Answer (score 2):

From my point of view, you should use a RecyclerView instead of a ListView. And in this case the adapter could subscribe to ItemChanged to add/remove/move items in the list.

I worked on some thing that can (I thing) be reused : https://github.com/Ideine/Xmf2/blob/develop-rx/src/Xmf2.Rx.Droid/ListElement/BaseReactiveRecyclerViewAdapter.cs

Comment: Isnt there a implementation for the ListView using any sort of RxUI-adopter or RxUI concept?

Comment: ListView really has bad performance when you have many elements so they are not widely used since the RecyclerView is available. I guess that's why there is no built-in adapter in ReactiveUI for ListView.
But if you really want to use ListView, I think you can easily adapt RecyclerView adapter to be used in ListView, both are pretty close in terms of behavior